# Autofac System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

Tags: c#, multithreading, autofac

I created autofac instance per matching lifetime scope and create child scope if parent scope already exist but i got exception.

Please see the code and stack trace below.

**Code**

```
public static class App {
   private static AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope> _upperScope;

   public static AsyncLocal<int> Number = new AsyncLocal<int>();

   public static ILifetimeScope NewScope(IContainer container) {
        if (_upperScope?.Value != null)
           return _upperScope.Value.BeginLifetimeScope();

        _upperScope = new AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope> {Value = container.BeginLifetimeScope("test")};
        _upperScope.Value.CurrentScopeEnding += (sender, args) => _upperScope.Value = null;
        return _upperScope.Value;
   }
}

[Fact]
public void Test1() {
     var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
     containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassOne>().AsSelf().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("test");
     var container = containerBuilder.Build();

     var tasks = new List<Task>();

     tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {
         using (var scope = App.NewScope(container)) {
             scope.Resolve<ClassOne>();
         }
     }));

     tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {
         using (var scope = App.NewScope(container)) {
             scope.Resolve<ClassOne>();
         }
     }));

     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

[Click here for stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPai.png)

Comment: The stack trace?

Comment: Click the stack trace link below the code.

Comment: Please don't post [images of exceptions or stack traces](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you assigned the `AsyncLocal<T>` more than once instead of only once. You should instantiate it once and then assign the `Value` property multiple time, this property will be *unique* per thread.

ie :

```
private static AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope> _upperScope = new AsyncLocal<ILifetimeScope>();
```

and then

```
_upperScope.Value = container.BeginLifetimeScope("test");
```

Comment: Thanks Cyril Durand.